# Asp.net core api I can't enter more than one data on the same line

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-core-webapi

[I have 3 tables, customer table has one to many relation with the other tables](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Xn2hl.png)
a customer needs to add more than one address and phone number. With HTTPGET, I can pull data as follows, but I cannot perform crud operations.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZJBUd.png)

GET:

```
    [HttpGet("{id}")]
    public async Task<ActionResult<Customer>> GetCustomer(int id)
    {

        var customers = _context.Customers
            .Include(customer => customer.Adresses)
            .Include(customer=> customer.Phones)
            .Where(customer => customer.CId == id)
            .FirstOrDefault();

        if (customers == null)
        {
            return NotFound();
        }

        return customers;
    }
```

POST:

```
    [HttpPost]
    public async Task<ActionResult<Customer>> PostCustomer(Customer customer)
    {
        
        _context.Customers.Add(customer);
        try
        {
            await _context.SaveChangesAsync();
        }
        catch (DbUpdateException)
        {
            if (CustomerExists(customer.CId))
            {
                return Conflict();
            }
            else
            {
                throw;
            }
        }

        return CreatedAtAction("GetCustomer", new { id = customer.CId }, customer);
    }
```

I can't enter more than one data on the same line

I want to receive customer information (how many addresses and phone numbers) at the same time as a record, I don't know how to do this.

Comment: _"I can't enter more than one data on the same line"_ - TBH it is not very clear what is the problem.

Comment: can u saw the json image, I want customers to be able to enter their addresses and phone numbers in the customer table as many times as they want. I can receive this data with json data, but I cannot send this data.

Comment: But WHY you _"cannot perform crud operations"_? What is stopping you?

Comment: I dont know how to use with relational tables

Comment: There are [examples](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/data/ef-mvc/update-related-data?view=aspnetcore-7.0#update-the-instructors-controller-1), have you tried those?

Comment: Hi @Megas, it seems you want to insert one `Customer` with multiple Phone and Address, right? Could you pls share your whole three models instead of table design?